# WPF assign static object to a DataContext in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, static, datacontext

I'm in a situation where I have to use a `static` object as my `DataContext`.
I have read many posts that recommends a `Singleton` class instead. However, I can't go this route due to design constraint.

I would like to assign a static object to my control `DataContext` as follows:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
   <local:ViewModelA>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

However it keeps telling me it is not usable object because it is not define a public constructor.

In my static view-model, I have a static constructor but it is not public due to C# constraints.

Thank you

Comment: What is a static object? There are static classes and objects, which are instances of non-static classes. Your XAML creates an instance of the non-static class `ViewModelA`, which therefore needs a non-static parameterless constructor.

Comment: My viewmodel is a static class.

Comment: then no you cant do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only assign an instance of a (non-static) class to the `DataContext` property, not a class.

You may however have a binding to a static property `SomeProperty` of your static class, like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:ViewModelA.SomeProperty)}" />
```

Comment: I think this is only possible in 4.5 or 4.6+

Comment: Possible since WPF 4.5.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for the hint. Why the () for the path important ? It would not work without it. With the () I'm getting an invalid markup error. But if run the project the usercontrol is behaving as expected. I'm using xaml 4.5.2

Comment: @Clemens I closed Visual Studio and reopened it and now it like the syntax. Don't you find this behavior weird ?

Comment: Please see section *PropertyPath for Objects in Data Binding* -> *Single Property, Attached or Otherwise Type-Qualified* in [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451(v=vs.110).aspx) for why the parentheses are necessary.

Comment: @Clemens I'm still getting invalid markup error. If I close the solution and reopen it, the error would go away. After one rebuild it comes back. I cleaned up the ShadowCache folder, the error went away for a while and came back after 5 or 6 rebuilds. Any idea why ?

Comment: A bug in XAML Designer?

Comment: @Clemens  Is it a known issue ? or you are guessing ? :)

Comment: There are a few known issues with the designer. You might search the web.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make everything in the class static but make the actual class not static, which would give you a similar effect to it being static.